# Oracle gather_database_stats for specific partition(s)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

```
select * from v$version
BANNER                                                                          
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.4.0  Production  
TNS for IBM/AIX RISC System/6000: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
```

I'm looking to use DBMS_STATS.GATHER_DATABASE_STATS using the obj_filter_list parameter to gather stats on specific tables & partitions.
I realise that Oracle can automatically gather stats and that this is often the best/most effective approach, but cleverer people than I have identified that we also nee to add this capability to allow us to focus/specify stats gathering when required.
The issue I'm having is that if I'm 'just' gathering stats on the table (using gather_database_stats), no issues, dbms_stats.gather_database_stats does its job as expected. However, when I add a partition name to the obj_filter_list, statistics are not gathered. I can only assume that I'm being a bit thick and either I'm misunderstanding the process, or I'm doing something wrong.

Code I'm using (in practice, the population of the filter list will actually be done via querying a table which will have the relevant details) to try to gather stats.:

```
declare
    filter_list dbms_stats.objecttab := dbms_stats.objecttab();
begin
    filter_list.extend(2);
    filter_list(1).ownname := 'USER01';
    filter_list(1).objname := 'TABLEABC';
    filter_list(1).objtype := 'TABLE';
    filter_list(1).partname := 'PART_CURR';
    
    filter_list(2).ownname := 'USER02';
    filter_list(2).objname := 'TAB_MYTAB';
    filter_list(2).objtype := 'TABLE';
    filter_list(2).partname := 'PART2023'    ;
    
    dbms_stats.gather_database_stats(obj_filter_list => filter_list);
end;
/
```

Any insights greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

As explained by Jim in a comment, Adding `OPTIONS => 'GATHER AUTO'` to the `DBMS_STATS.GATHER_DATABASE_STATS` call will force Oracle to gather stats only for the objects listed in `OBJ_FILTER_LIST`. If you add that argument to the below code it will work correctly.

---

**Original answer**

Your code looks correct to me, but I can't get it to work on 19c. Instead of calling DBMS_STATS.GATHER_DATABASE_STATS and using the parameter OBJ_FILTER_LIST, call DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS and use the parameter PARTNAME:

```
begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(ownname => user, tabname => 'TABLEABC', partname => 'PART_CURR');
end;
/
```

Below is a fully reproducible example based on your code. It shows that despite the seemingly correct parameter values, the LAST_ANALYZED fields are all set to NULL, which means that no statistics are being gathered.

```
-- drop table TABLEABC;
-- drop table TAB_MYTAB;

create table TABLEABC(a number, b number)
partition by list(a)
(
    partition p1 values (1),
    partition PART_CURR values(3)
);

create table TAB_MYTAB(a number, b number)
partition by list(a)
(
    partition p1 values (1),
    partition PART2023 values(3)
);

declare
    filter_list dbms_stats.objecttab := dbms_stats.objecttab();
    output_object_list dbms_stats.objecttab;
begin
    filter_list.extend(2);
    filter_list(1).ownname := user;
    filter_list(1).objname := 'TABLEABC';
    filter_list(1).objtype := 'TABLE';
    filter_list(1).partname := 'PART_CURR';

    filter_list(2).ownname := user;
    filter_list(2).objname := 'TAB_MYTAB';
    filter_list(2).objtype := 'TABLE';
    filter_list(2).partname := 'PART2023'    ;

    dbms_stats.gather_database_stats(obj_filter_list => filter_list, objlist => output_object_list);
end;
/

select last_analyzed from dba_tables where table_name in ('TABLEABC', 'TAB_MYTAB');
select last_analyzed, dba_tab_partitions.* from dba_tab_partitions where table_name in ('TABLEABC', 'TAB_MYTAB');
```

But calling DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS with the PARTNAME parameter will set the LAST_ANALYZED values correctly.

One of the [few sources](https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/post/how-do-i-restrict-concurrent-statistics-gathering-to-a-small-set-of-tables-from-a-single-schema) that mentions this filter parameter implies there was a bug where the filter list only works if you also use the output object list. However, even when I set that output parameter, the functionality still doesn't work. And I can't even find the referenced bug number on Oracle support.

The feature seems rare and buggy. Even if you do find some way to make OBJ_FILTER_LIST work, you should probably avoid it anyway.

Comment: Many thanks for the response Jon (especially for confirming that I wasn't making some blatantly obvious mistake :) ). The blog post you linked to was one of the first I read through on that topic. The main reason for wanting to do it this way, was to leverage concurrent stats, which I don't think would be viable if I'm calling gather_table_stats (unless I'm missing something - which is VERY possible :) ). Back to the drawing board I guess.
Thanks again.

Comment: @Jim I would guess that `GATHER_TABLE_STATS` works with concurrent statistics, since [the concurrent statistics example in the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/tgsql/gathering-optimizer-statistics.html#GUID-F7874BC5-001C-4F92-B88A-53BFA3804C11) uses `GATHER_SCHEMA_STATS`.

But there are just too many configuration options and black-box Oracle behaviors to thoroughly troubleshoot concurrent statistics problems. I hate to say it, but I think this might be a problem that only Oracle support can solve.

Comment: John, apologies, I didn't see that you had responded. Many thanks for your input. I'm looking at this again, so if I find anything of use, I'll add here.

Comment: FWIW we managed to get this working. Had to set the options parameter to 'GATHER AUTO'. With this, the filter list is 'obeyed' and any stale/null stats are gathered.